# Как в bootstrap отключить изменение порядка следования адаптивных блоков

Tags: css, bootstrap, joomla, bootstrap4, joomla3

Делаю сайт на Joomla. Шаблон Helix3.
Нужно, чтобы на мониторах с шириной 600px и 800px сайт выглядел также как и на больших мониторах (1920х1080 и выше). А из-за Bootstrap он складывается. Блоки располагаются один под другим вертикально.
Я понимаю, что это адаптивный дизайн сайта и в нём по порядку следуют адаптивные блоки в макете. И связано это с col-md-push, или col-md-pull. Но в Bootstrap я не силен. Потому и прошу помощи.
Может есть возможность указать размер монитора при котором адаптивный дизайн не нужно применять?

Comment: Удалите все `@media`-блоки из CSS и верстка перестанет адаптироваться под разрешение.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил вопрос таким способом

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75"
```